# JSON vs. Pickle security

Tags: python, json, pickle

I recently came across the security problems of the Python pickle and cPickle modules.
Obviously, there are no real security measures implemented in pickle unless you overwrite
the find_class method as a basic modification to get a bit more security. But I often
heard that JSON is more secure.

Can anyone elaborate a bit on this?`Why is JSON more secure than pickle?

Thanks a lot!
Mark

Comment: What do you mean by "came across"? You read something that said they were insecure? You implemented something that got hacked? Or what?

Comment: He probably read the big red warning at the top of the documentation of the pickle module in the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html .

Comment: Does the BSON package have same vulnerability as Pickle?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

json is more secure because it's fundamentally more limited.  The only python types that a json document can encode are `unicode`, `int`, `float`, `NoneType`, `bool`, `list` and `dict`.  these are marshaled/unmarshalled in a basically trivial fashion that isn't vulnerable to code injection attacks.

Answer (score 10):

Pickle's problem is that it will can invoke arbitrary Python code.  See http://nadiana.com/python-pickle-insecure  for details.  The JSON parser only has to create strings, numbers, lists, dicts, and so on.  It never creates user-defined classes, so it doesn't need to execute arbitrary Python.