# sending a screenshot using python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to take a screenshot and send it to another computer using python.
I've tried to do it in many different ways. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to do it.
I would appreciate your help!

server:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket


server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1111))
server_socket.listen(1)
print('Waiting For Connection...')
(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
print('Connected to: ', client_address[0])


img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10, 10, 500, 500))
photo_to_send= img.tobytes()
size = len(photo_to_send)
client_socket.send(bytes(str(size), 'utf-8'))

while size >= 0:
    msg = photo_to_send[:4096]
    client_socket.send(bytes(str(msg), 'utf-8'))
    photo_to_send= photo_to_send[4096:]
```

client:

```
import socket
from PIL import Image


my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1111))
print("Connected to the server")

size = int(my_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8'))

the_photo = ""
the_photo = the_photo.encode('utf-8')

while size > 0:
    data = my_socket.recv(4096)
    size -= len(data)
    the_photo += data


img_to_save = Image.frombytes("RGB", (490,490), the_photo)
img_to_save .save("screenshot.png")
```

Comment: What kind of transport would you like to use? What are your problems with that?

Comment: my problem is that the client does not get all the bytes or that he gets to many bytes. As a reasult the client gets an extremly blurry picture.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) to serialize your Image objects. Pickle just converts an python object into bytes. [pickle.dumps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.dumps) just encodes it to bytes and [pickle.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.loads) decodes it back.

Hope this helps!

Comment: [Maybe dont use pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752259/python-why-pickle) messagePack seems the safer alternative

Comment: I think for images pickle is better

Comment: I will try to learn about it and use it.
Thank you for your help!! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sending the textual value of the length immediately before the data itself. For example, if the image data started with `AAABBB`, you would be sending

```
1234AAABBB...
```

But if the image was bigger, you might send something like

```
56789AAABBB...
```

The client has no way of telling where the length ends and the data starts! To fix this, you need to send a *fixed size* length parameter. If you still want to a textual length, you could use `zfill`:

```
client_socket.send(str(size).zfill(16).encode())
...
size = int(my_socket.recv(16).decode())
```

(where 16 is chosen to be long enough to fit any possible image size)

---

This is not terribly efficient; real protocols usually use binary encoding:

```
client_socket.send(struct.pack('>I', size))
...
size, = struct.unpack('>I', my_socket.recv(4))
```

But this may be more complex than you need for your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
Unfortunately this didn't solve my problem.
My problem is that the bytes the server sends and the bytes the client gets are a little bit different.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I encoded the photo twice.
Thanks for your help!
I really appreciate it!

Here is the solution:

server:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import socket


server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1112))
server_socket.listen(1)
print('Waiting For Connection...')
(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
print('Connected to: ', client_address[0])


img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(10, 10, 500, 500))
photo_to_send = img.tobytes()

size = len(photo_to_send)
print(size)
print(photo_to_send)
client_socket.send(bytes(str(size), 'utf-8'))

client_socket.send(photo_to_send)
```

client:

```
import socket
from PIL import Image

my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1112))
print("Connected to the server")

size = int(my_socket.recv(10).decode('utf-8'))
print(size)

the_photo = my_socket.recv(size)

print(the_photo)
img_to_save = Image.frombytes("RGB", (490, 490), the_photo)
img_to_save.save("screenshot.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

`struct` and `pickle` makes everything easy for you.

server.py

```
imageBytes = pickle.dumps(image)
sock.sendall(struct.pack("L", len(imageBytes)) + imageBytes)
```

client.py

```
data = b""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L")
while True:
    data += sock.recv(payload_size)
    packedImageSize = data[:payload_size]
    imageSize = struct.unpack("L", packedImageSize)[0]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    while len(data) < imageSize:
        data += sock.recv(65000)
    frameData = data[:imageSize]
    data = data[imageSize:]
    frame = pickle.loads(frameData)
```