# Why np.arrays and lists work with `allow_pickle=False`, but dictionaries do not?

Tags: python, numpy

This question involves `np.save` and `np.load` best practices. Since the newer numpy version 1.16.3, the default in `np.load` is set to `allow_pickle=False`.

After saving a list, the further load declaration works just fine with the default `allow_pickle=False`:

```
>> x = [0, 1, 2]                            
>> np.save('my_x_list.npy', x)                
>> loaded_x = np.load('my_x_list.npy') 
>> loaded_x                        
Out: array([0, 1, 2])
```

The same holds for a numpy array:

```
>> y = np.arange(10)                            
>> np.save('my_y_numpy_array.npy', y)                
>> loaded_y = np.load('my_y_numpy_array.npy') 
>> loaded_y                          
Out: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

However, a dictionary yields this error:

```
>> mydict = {'a': 4, 'b': 5}
>> np.save('my_dict.npy', mydict)
>> loaded_z = np.load('my_z_dict.npy')
ValueError: Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False
```

As far as I understand, dictionaries, lists and numpy arrays are all `Object arrays`. Hence, one would expect numpy arrays or lists to raise this error as well. Why is this error raised with dictionaries and is not raised with numpy arrays or lists ?

Comment: The default `allow_pickle` was changed for safety reasons.  It reduces the chances of loading something bad from the file.  You have to explicitly allow a pickle load for a file from a trusted source.  Without pickle, the `load` can only be a safe, numeric (or string) array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I understand, dictionaries, lists and `numpy` arrays are all `Object arrays`

No, it depends on the data type of the values in the list. The reason why you are encountering this error is because you are trying to create a `numpy.array` from a `dict` object, which will always give an “Object Array”, that is to say a `numpy.array` with `dtype=object`. See

```python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.array({'a': 4, 'b': 5})
array({'a': 4, 'b': 5}, dtype=object)
```

Whereas, when using a list of numbers (integers, floats, complex numbers, etc.) to create a `numpy.array`, that array will have a number `dtype`, that does not require to be pickled here.

```python
>>> np.array([1, 2, 3]).dtype
dtype('int64')
```

You *can* load a dictionary (or even other `object`s) from a file into a `numpy.array`, [using the `allow_pickle` parameter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load), *e.g.*

```python
np.load('dictionary.npy', allow_pickle=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. Thank you for your comment. I understand the default `allow_pickle=False` was set for security reasons. In this example, the `npy` file is generated from my script every time it runs; is there a risk for loading wrong data in this scenario ?

Comment: Using `pickle` is fine to me in a local-experimention scenario. Using it in production might be fine to transfert Python objects between your services (with precautions). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21752259/python-why-pickle for more insights on that matter.