# Save and be able to load a list in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I'm trying to make a quiz maker and loader in python 3.9 and I'm wondering how do I save a list of questions and answers. This is so you can make a list then save it to a file and load it to answer it.

```
    questions = [
        input("Enter question 1: "),
        input("Enter question 2: "),
        input("Enter question 3: "),
        input("Enter question 4: "),
        input("Enter question 5: "),
        input("Enter question 6: "),
        input("Enter question 7: "),
        input("Enter question 8: "),
        input("Enter question 9: "),
        input("Enter question 10: "),
    ]
```

Comment: You can use any of the file formats like txt, csv, etc.
Or you can use pickle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-can-i-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict

Comment: Using Pickle depending on how the usecase might be unsafe. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21752259/4440330

Comment: It seems to be fine as its just for a quiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your usecase, I don't think it would be wise to use a pickle file. Instead I would suggest to convert the `list` into a `string` and store it in a simple `txt` file. Here is a sample of how you can do it:

```py
questions = [
        input("Enter question 1: "),
        input("Enter question 2: "),
        input("Enter question 3: "),
        input("Enter question 4: "),
        input("Enter question 5: "),
        input("Enter question 6: "),
        input("Enter question 7: "),
        input("Enter question 8: "),
        input("Enter question 9: "),
        input("Enter question 10: "),
    ]

with open('outfile.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('SEP'.join(questions)) #You can replace the SEP with a newline or say a pipe operator (|) or something similar
    
with open('outfile.txt') as f:
    print(f.read().split("SEP")) #Returns the list of questions as you have earlier
```

Answer (score 1):

python's [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) library is often a good choice, but it is a file format that is unreadable by humans. If you want the convenience of being able to open up a list of questions in a simple text editor, I'd recommend simply saving your list of questions as lines in a txt file. You've already figured out how to get a list of user inputs, so you just need to iterate over that list of strings, and write them to a file.

```py
#create a new txt file and open it in write mode
with open(r"C:\some\file\path.txt", "w") as f: #use a 'raw' string to handle windows file paths more easily
    for question in questions:
        f.write(question + "\n") #add a newline to the end of the question so each question is on it's own line in the text file
```

Reading the file back into python is similarly easy, but you could take the time to add a few features like ignoring blank lines, and perhaps even including a syntax for comments which should be ignored.

```py
#open the file in read mode
questions = [] #create an empty list to read the questions into from the file
with open(r"C:\some\file\path.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip(): #if we strip whitespace from the front and back of a line is there any text left
            if not line.strip().startswith("#"): #if the first non whitespace character is a '#', treat the line as a comment and skip it
                questions.append(line)
```

Comment: What if it is a multiline question? Why do you need to specify the 'r' read mode since it is default. This answer has a lot of pitfalls and redundancies!! Also, the comment part (#)... where did that come from?

Comment: @paradocslover I specify `"r"` mode for clarity for the sake of a new programmer. It can be omitted. Multi-line entry is not realistic if the input is coming from `input()`, and using newline as the separator makes it more human readable. If the intent is to include human readability to the file type, and there is an expectation that a use might use a text editor, it is very likely to end up with extra blank lines. The comment syntax was just a quick thought I had to add some value to taking the time to read my answer...